# Showing a function defined on a finite field is a bijection

Tags: elementary-number-theory, finite-fields

Let $p$ be a prime and $d \in \mathbb{N}$.  If $(p-1,d)=1$ show that $f:F_p^x\to F_p^x$ given be $f(x)=x^d$.

When I first started this proof I considered two elements $a,b\in F_p^x$ where $a\neq b$.  Then $f(a)=a^d$ and $f(b)=b^d.$ However, this being in a finite field, could it be the case that $a^d=b^d$?  It's been a while since I have thought deeply about this topic, and now its bothering me that my answer wasn't satisfactory then or now.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2365304/589

Comment: The approach makes sense.  However, does it matter that it's $x^d$?  Since its a finite field, would it be possible that $a^d=b^d$ even thought $a /neq b$.

Comment: That's a different approach: proving that the map is injective. It suffices to prove that $x^d=1 \implies x=1$. Bézout is useful here too.

Comment: A good catch @lhf (and a nice generalization).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(d,p-1)=1\implies$ that for any generator $g$ of the multiplicative group of the field, $f(g)=g^d$ also generates.  Thus $f$ is surjective.  Thus bijective, by finiteness.

Comment: I follow part of this - I am trying to come up with a concrete example of this.  If I pick p=7, d=5.  I know that powers of 3 will generate the group.  I don't follow the relationship that occurs between $d$ and a generator $g$.

Comment: If $3$ generates the group, then so will $3^5$.

Comment: What I have in mind is the basic fact about cyclic groups:  $|g|=n\implies |g^k|=\dfrac n{\rm{gcd}(n,k)}$.